# How do I install android_filesystem_config headers?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile an application that includes android_filesystem_config.h. This file does not appear to be part of the NDK or SDK. Where can I obtain this library and how is it conventionally installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find that file in the android sources in system/core/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h.

In this source file it is stated the following:

```
/* This file is used to define the properties of the filesystem
 * images generated by build tools (mkbootfs and mkyaffs2image) and
 * by the device side of adb.
 */
```

You're right, it is not part of the SDK or the NDK.

I'm not so sure if you will be able to include this file in your application without performing some code tweaks. I suggest you try to compile the application together with the Android sources.